# Set#apply with argument `Unit`

Tags: scala

Scala Puzzlers presents this "puzzler":

```
scala> List("1", "2").toSet() + "3"
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res13: String = false3
```

The explanation notes that the above code de-sugars to:

`(List("1", "2").toSet[Any] apply ()) + "3"`

But why doesn't the following return `false`?

```
scala> Set("1")()
<console>:11: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (elem: String)Boolean in trait GenSetLike.
Unspecified value parameter elem.
       Set("1")()
               ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is smart enough to know that makes no sense for `Set[A]`.

`Set[A]#apply` has the signature:

```
apply(elem: A): Boolean
```

i.e., you *must* supply an argument of `A`, and `A` is invariant for `Set`. So if you try to supply `Unit` to `Set[Int]`, you will get a type mismatch, *not* `false`.

```
scala> Set("1")(())
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
              Set("1")(())
                       ^
```

Okay, well your question has one less set of parentheses than my code above. The compiler is assuming you're not trying to pass `Unit`, because you can't. If you had a `Set[Unit]`, you *could*.

```
scala> Set(())()
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
res41: Boolean = true
```

Comment: `Set[AnyVal](1)()`. Another way of saying it is that adapting the args fails if the types don't work out. I'm not clear on the "must supply" line.